# IndexError: tuple index out of range --— Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running a simple code that will read a json file, take the inputs and generate an output. But in one of the line, I am getting error

```
activities_obj = document.add_paragraph()
activities_obj = helper.format_alignment(activities_obj)
activities = helper.askForChoices(activities, "Choose extracurricular activities")
activity_string = "Beside coop experience, {}. Additionally, {}. {}. Last but not least, {}."
activiy_para = activity_string.format(*activities)
```

This was the code, the last line is giving the error:

```
activiy_para = activity_string.format(*activities)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Thank you

Comment: `activity_string` has 4 `{}` in it. So `activities` needs to have at least 4 elements. You'll get that error if the user chooses less than 4.

Comment: What should "Last but not least" say if the user only selects 3 activities?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing enough arguments to `activity_string.format(*activities)`

You need to pass dict with 4 keys,

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:42:10)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> activity_string = "Beside coop experience, {}. Additionally, {}. {}. Last but not least, {}."
>>> activities = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4'}
>>> activity_string.format(*activities)
'Beside coop experience, a. Additionally, b. c. Last but not least, d.'
>>>
```

What if you don't pass enough arguments,

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:42:10)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> activity_string = "Beside coop experience, {}. Additionally, {}. {}. Last but not least, {}."
>>> activities = {'a': '1'}
>>> activity_string.format(*activities)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>>
```